# How to collect multiple lines in a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, for-loop

I want to store multiple lines in a variable with a for loop.

I am using the below code but do not get the expected result.

```
start=720000003999086110
end=720000003999086119

for((c=$start; c<= $end; c++))


do
    list= lookupSerialNumber $c
    done
```

i want the below value to be stored in a variable and then i will use that variable in my Application CLI.

```
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086110
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086111
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086112
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086113
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086114
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086115
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086116
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086117
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086118
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086119
 ...
```

below is my Application cli code ,

```
 /opt/vs/bin/vscli -u $username -p $password <<EOF 
 +voucher,main,setup,lookupAndUpdate 
 +config 
 $list 
 exit 
 EOF
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why do you want to store commands in a variable? What are the commands you're trying to store? How are you going to use this variable later?

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself. Don't put it in a comment (where you can't use nice formatting).

Comment: Edited, Please check now.

Comment: So this isn't about commands at all. You're just building a long (multi-line) string.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. i want to store multiple lines in a variable and i will use that in cli. i can not run a for loop inside my CLI, thats the reason i am doing this.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using an array? Something like `list=()` and then `list+=("some value")`.

Comment: I Have tried using array, got the below error,
" line 8: lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086110: command not found"
My code as below,
    #!/bin/bash
    #set -x
    start=720000003999086110
    end=720000003999086119
    for((c=$start; c<= $end; c++))
 do
 list[$c]= "lookupSerialNumber $c"
 done

    echo "${list[@]}"

Comment: @jww, i am getting output like the below,
lookupSerialNumber 720000003999086110\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086111\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086112\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086113\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086114\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086115\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086116\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086117\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086118\nlookupSerialNumber 720000003999086119\n


i tried just with 
    list+="lookupSerialNumber $c\n"

Answer (score 2):

To create the variable `$list`:

```
list=$(printf 'lookupSerialNumber %s\n' $(seq "$start" "$end"))
```

```
printf -v list 'lookupSerialNumber %s\n' $(seq "$start" "$end")
```

The latter will have an extra newline at the end that you could remove with: `${list%$'\n'}`.

---

You can use command substitution `$(...)` inside here-docs:

```
cat <<EOF
...
$(printf 'lookupSerialNumber %s\n' $(seq "$start" "$end"))
...
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append to the previous results. I'm not sure if I understood you. If you want to store that command, the you can use:

```
start=720000003999086110
end=720000003999086119
list=""

for ((c=$start; c<= $end; c++))
do
    list="$list lookupSerialNumber $c"
done
```

Otherwise, if you want to store the results of the execution of that command, the code could be:

```
start=720000003999086110
end=720000003999086119
list=""

for ((c=$start; c<= $end; c++))
do
    list="$list $(lookupSerialNumber $c)"
done
```

You can also use arrays for all of this. There are several approaches to the problem. The best will be determined by the usage that you will do to this data.